# Efficient extraction of coefficient from generating function

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, exponential-function, generating-functions

In Mathematica I give input for generating function:

```
Series[Exp[x + x^2/2], {x, 0, 6}]
```

It gives output:

$$1 + x + x^2 + \frac{2x^3}{3} + \frac{5x^4}{12} + \frac{13x^5}{60} + \frac{19x^6}{180} + O(x)^{7}$$

But in particular I am interested in the coefficients of the output of

`Series[Exp[x + x^2/2 + x^3/3 + x^4/4 + ... + x^k/k]]`

For some $k$.

Is there an efficient way to extract any particular coefficient of this output?

Comment: I assume you know the series for $e^u$. Just replace $u$ with $x+(x^2/2)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you mean $e^u = 1+u+u^2/2+u^3/6+u^4/24+u^5/120+...$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $e^{x+x^2/2} = 1+x+x^2/2+(x+x^2/2)^2/2+(x+x^2/2)^3/6+(x+x^2/2)^4/24+(x+x^2/2)^5/120+...$ is there a better way to extract the coefficient of a particular term? For example could I quickly extract "19/180" if I wanted the coefficient of $x^6$?

Comment: What about $e^{x+\frac{x^2}2}=e^x \times e^{\frac{x^2}2}$ and making the product of the two series ? I suppose it would be more tedious that using Gerry Myerson's hint.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am trying to find an efficient approach. Maybe I should make a new question now that Gerry clarified the meaning?

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Now, it is much better !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function as

$$ F_k(x) = \prod_{j=1}^k \exp \left(\dfrac{x^j}{j} \right) $$

Thus $F_k(x) = F_{k-1}(x) \exp\left(\dfrac{x^k}{k}\right)$, and the coefficient of $x^m$ is

$$ [x^m] F_k(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor m/k \rfloor} \dfrac{[x^{m-kj}]\; F_{k-1}(x)}{k^j j!}$$

Of course, for $m \le k$ the coefficient will be $1$, because
$\sum_{j=1}^k x^j/j = -\ln(1-x) + O(x^{k+1})$.
You may also find it amusing to show that
$$[x^{k+1}]\; F_k(x) = \dfrac{k}{k+1}$$
and
$$[x^{k+2}]\; F_k(x) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{k+1} - \dfrac{1}{k+2} $$
Hmmm, looks like a pattern emerging ... 
$$ [x^{k+j}]\; F_k(x) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{k+1} - \dfrac{1}{k+2} - \ldots - \dfrac{1}{k+j}\ \text{for}\ k \ge j-1$$
(these being the cases where only the terms for $j=0$ and $j=1$ occur in the recursive formula)